# Running a mystery in Burning Wheel

Tags: gm-techniques, burning-wheel, investigation

As part of an ongoing "Uncampaign" (organized group play of many different systems, to get a feel for new and current trends), I'll be running a Burning Wheel game this weekend.

Having only run Mouseguard in the past, this question is soliciting tips for running Burning Wheel in general and running mysteries in Burning Wheel specifically. The Genre is set in something like the "Powers" universe, where the PCs will be mundane cops investigating crimes by supers.

What should I keep in mind when running Burning Wheel for the first time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My advice would be to do exactly the opposite of everything you intend to do. You are really bending Burning Wheel past the point of structural failure.

It is optimized for long-term play and, beyond bloody versus tests, is pretty complex

The existing lifepaths are the game's setting; making your own set is nontrivial

"Mysteries" aren't what it is about, BITs are

I'd suggest Mouse Guard would be a better fit for a one-shot, and it pretty effortlessly handles mysteries too. Or, if it must be Burning Wheel, run the demo The Sword, which is awesome.